# Superlinearly converging infinite series with a closed form

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Let $(x_n)_n$ converge to $L$. Then it converges to $L$ superlinearly if and only if
> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln |x_{n+1}-L|}{\ln |x_n-L|}\gt 1.$$

For example:
If $x_N=\sum_{n=0}^N \frac{1}{n!}$, then $\lim_{N\to\infty}x_N=e$ and $x_N=\frac{e\Gamma (N+1,1)}{\Gamma (N+1)}$, but
$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln |x_{N+1}-L|}{\ln |x_N-L|}=1$,
so the convergence is not superlinear.

I observed that a lot of "popular" series with a closed form do not converge superlinearly. Does there exist a superlinearly converging infinite series with a closed form?

Answer (score 0):

Why, many, but then $x_n$ won't be nice.

Say, $x_n$ is the n'th Newton's iteration for $\sqrt2\left(\text{that is, }x_1=1, x_{n+1}={x_n+2/x_n\over2}\right)$.

Now, Newton's method for any reasonably well-behaved function is known to have *quadratic* convergence, which basically means that the error on each step is about as small as the square of that on the previous step. In short, your limit for this sequence will be $2$.

On the other hand, we know that $x_n$ is A001601(n)/A051009(n) = A001333($2^n$)/A000129($2^n$), and the latter two sequences are defined by a simple linear recurrence (the same one, but with different starting conditions), so they must have a Binet-like closed form. So after all, $x_n$ **does** have an elementary closed form as well, albeit an ugly one.

That's an example for you.

Comment: This is not an infinite series.

Comment: Sure. It is a sequence, much like $x_n$ in your question. Well, then consider a series consisting of $y_n=x_{n+1}-x_n$.

Comment: What would $y_n$ converge to? Would that have a closed form?

Comment: Well, if $x_n$ has a closed form, then obviously $y_n$ does too. Also, $y_n$ converge to $0$, and their sum converges to $\sqrt2$.